# How to load php file according to the div clicked even after refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have div as follows and what I am doing is basically load a default PHP file on ready of document and than i load different PHP files based on div clicked.

```
<div class="menu">
   <div id="home" class="menu_align active_one">Home</div>
   <div id="write" class="menu_align">Write</div>
   <div id="activity" class="menu_align">Notifications</div>
</div>
<div id="main_content"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#main_content").load('home.php');
 });
$("#home").click(function(){
   $("#main_content").load('home.php');
});
$("#write").click(function(){
   $("#main_content").load('write.php');
});
$("#activity").click(function(){
   $("#main_content").load('notifs.php');
});
```

So what I want is that if user clicks on Write and refresh the page then main_content should load write.php and same for all other div.

Comment: Your click handle must be inside (document).ready(function(){});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event is outside [`$(document).ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) add it inside [`$(document).ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). Those function which are inside .[ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function will be execute when the DOM is fully loaded. To track clicked page, save it to [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or `cookies`. And on page load check if the [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) has value or not, if it has load that page else load default page. Here is working example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(localStorage.getItem("clicked")){
    var clickedPage = localStorage.getItem("clicked");
    $("#main_content").load(clickedPage);
  } else {
    $("#main_content").load('home.php');
  }
  
  $("#home").click(function(){
    $("#main_content").load('home.php'); 
    localStorage.setItem('clicked', 'home.php');
  });
  $("#write").click(function(){
    $("#main_content").load('write.php');
    localStorage.setItem('clicked', 'write.php');
  });
  $("#activity").click(function(){
    $("#main_content").load('notifs.php');
    localStorage.setItem('clicked', 'notifs.php');
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div id="home" class="menu_align active_one">Home</div>
  <div id="write" class="menu_align">Write</div>
  <div id="activity" class="menu_align">Notifications</div>
</div>
<div id="main_content"></div>
```

Comment: I tried that but the issue i am facing is it loads home.php after refresh even when user has clicked on write div before refreshing the page. I want a functionality where if user clicks on write div and then refresh the page then it should display write.php and not home.php

Comment: I will be really thankful if you solve it and share it here. I am trying it for many days still no luck.

Comment: @MackTrivedi answer updated. Check it once do it work or not.

Comment: Wow it works great. Thanks a lot, you solved it in minutes. Thanks again !

Comment: how do I change background of clicked div and keep it even after refresh using same method ? The issue i am facing is that on saving clicked div id into localstorage and then trying to change it's css throws error saying '.css not a function '.